# *ngFor in *ngFor on firebase database

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I use firebase database and AngularFireDatabase. 
I can't display value from a variable in *ngFor, this *ngFor is in other *ngFor.

```
    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    db.list('/devices/').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => { 
        return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })) }))
        .subscribe(o => { this.devices = o });
  }


    <div *ngFor="let d of db.devices;">
    <h4>{{d.name}}</h4>
    <div *ngFor="let s of d.sensors;">
    <p>Sensor value: {{s.value}}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Hey. The error already states that either `db.devices` or `d.sensors` isn't an *array*, but an *object*. `*ngFor` only works for arrays.

Comment: Using an *ngFor inside another *ngFor is possible, so your template logic looks correct. "d.sensors" needs to be an array though, I am guessing that it is not. Can you console log "this.devices" inside your subscribe() and see what you get?

Comment: can you do the following outside of the loop and show the response: {{d.sensors | json}}

Answer (score 3):

`*ngFor` , Like any `for` loops , Can only run on [Iterables](https://javascript.info/iterable).
The error occurs because you try to run on an object that is not iterable.

try printing your objects and see that they are Iterables

Comment: so, how to use db.devices to display children's values?